# jQuery Draggable: memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui, memory-leaks

I have a simple html table that is being updated periodically by some websocket handler:

```
<table class="schedule">
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="order"><div>Text 1</div></td>
        <td class="order">Text 2</td>
        <td class="order">Text 3</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

(Total of 14 columns and about 10-20 rows, first cell in each row has a div element with no classes; rows have no css classes either.)

All rows/cells are being removed from the table on each update and only after the new "order" cells are added to it dynamically; there are no duplicate tables in the dom (checked); cells must be draggable, so if I add the following line at the end of the function that updates the table the page leaks about 1 mb in heap, adds about 200 new listeners and about 200 new nodes to the DOM. GC never collects those objects:

```
var dnd = $("table.schedule td.order").draggable();
```

If if comment that line out everything works great, GC collects everything. I suspect that the problem is in my selector but I spent hours now with Chrome's Tools and still can't see where the problem is. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably initializing `draggable()` over an over again on exisiting draggable elements, adding new listeners and stuff.

Try using [destroy](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-destroy) method like

```
$("table.schedule td.order").draggable("destroy").draggable();
```

If you can make use of the [sortable](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable) widget instead, it has a [`refresh`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh) that identifies new elements which will probably suit you better.

Comment: According to my tests, destroying the widget prior to removing rows from the table and initing the new ones after the update is done in my case just slows down the whole thing a bit but doesn't have any "cleaning" effect at all.

Comment: @Pikkolat maybe the rest of your code has a memory leak. You should share a [mcve]...

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, if I just comment out the line with draggable everything else works perfectly. So, I don't think anything in the rest of the code has leaks.

Comment: Well if you need further help from people, you need to provide further info. I don't think anybody is going to create such a demo in order to help you. If you are so certain that it's a bug of jQuery UI, raise a bug report at their site, even they are going to ask you for a demo. You are the one asking for help. good luck.